# Best way to use controller in directives

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a directive so that I can reuse a view in different pages. Lets call it `my-directive`:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    .
    .
    .
    templateUrl: reuse.html
});
```

Now I want to use this directive on page1.html and page2.html.

```
<div>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

I don't know if my assumptions are correct, so kindly verify, refute, or provide a better idea. My questions are:

(1) Suppose I have two different controllers for these two pages but using the same directive, should I put the controllers this way:

```
<div ng-controller="Page1Ctrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-controller="Page2Ctrl">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

(2) If I will use a single controller anyway for both of the pages, should I:

(a) same as what's done in number (1)

or

(b) place the controller in template html, like this:

reuse.html

```
<div ng-controller="ReuseCtrl">
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

or

(c) define the controller in the directive:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    .
    .
    .
    templateUrl: reuse.html,
    controller: function() {
    .
    .
    .
    },
    controllerAs: ReuseCtrl
});
```

Comment: Directives should be **context independent**, ie should not rely on parent controllers at all. Anything you want to make available to a directive should be passed in through `scope` arguments

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it is to call the controller in the directive. ex:

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('directiveName', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          templateUrl: 'views/myDirective.html',
          controller: 'controllerNameCtrl'
        }
    })
```

Comment: How about in case (1)? I want to use two different controllers?

Comment: This a special situation so then you could call direct the controller like <mydirective ng-controller="secondCtrl"></mydirective>

Answer (score 0):

Directives are behaviour. If you truly need two different controllers, then create two different directives.

If, however, you only want two different controllers in order to access some property on them (e.g. `$scope.books`), you are better off passing that argument into the directive.

For example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: { books: '=' },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // use scope.books here
        }
    }
});

<my-directive books="model.books"></my-directive>
```